# How to filter out only the selected records in a Many2many field from all the other records in the model in odoo13 using domain filter

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am making a package model in which one can make packages and use it in the sales order, my model's name is sale.package.

```
class Package(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.package'
    _description = 'Package table'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    width = fields.Float(string='Width')
    height = fields.Float(string='Height')
    length = fields.Float(string='Length')
    maximum_weight = fields.Float(string='Maximum weight')
```

In order to use it in the sale order form, I inherited the sale.order model and added a Many2many field to the sale order which selects the previously made packages, I also created an Onchange function that updates an One2many field in a newly made page in the same sale order.

```
class SaleOrderPackage(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    packs = fields.Many2many('sale.package', string='Package')
    package_lines = fields.One2many('sale.package.lines', 'line_name', string='Package Lines')

    @api.onchange('packs')
    def _onchange_packs(self):
        for rec in self:
            lines = [(5, 0, 0)]
            for line in self.packs:
                values = {
                    'name_on_line': line.name,
                    'line_width': line.width,
                    'line_height': line.height,
                    'line_length': line.length,
                    'line_maximum_weight': line.maximum_weight,
                }
                lines.append((0, 0, values))
            rec.package_lines = lines
```

Up to this everything is going fine, my new requirement is to add a smart button to the same sale order and upon clicking it, a tree view of the selected packages in the sale order must show up. I have added the smart button and defined a function in the python file which returns not only the selected but also all the packages made with the model.

```
    def selected_packages(self):
        print(self.packs)
        return {
            'name': 'Selected Packages',
            'domain': [],
            'view_type': 'form',
            'res_model': 'sale.package',
            'view_id': False,
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window'
        }
```

As I am only a week into learning Odoo I am unable to figure out how to use the domain filter in this context, Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried posting this question to the Odoo forum? https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/tag/python-86/questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to show only the selected packages, You have just to filter records using their id.

Use [self.packs.ids](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#record-set-information) to return the list of actual record ids corresponding to selected packages:

```
'domain': [('id', 'in', self.packs.ids)],
```